# how to get specific file names using c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file, filenames

I have  10 zip files in a folder having path like this

> TargetDirectory =  "C:\docs\folder\"

some of the  zip files names are like this

```
abc-19870908.Zip 
abc-19870908.zip
abc-12345678.zip
```

and some are like this...

```
doc.zip
doc123.zip  
..
```

I am getting all file names by using following code...

```
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory); 
foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
{
  // here I need to compare , 
  // I mean I want to get only these files which are having 
  // these type of  filenames `abc-19870908.Zip`

  if (filename == "")
  {

       // I want to do something
   }
}
```

What i have to put in the double quotes  in this line `if(filename == "")` to get like `abc-19870908.Zip` these filenames.

Would any one please suggest any idea about this?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're only interested in zip files containing a dash, you can provide a search pattern to Directory.GetFiles.

```
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory, "*-*.zip");
```

Check out this link for more information on those search patterns: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I guess you can do

```
 if (filename.Contains("-"))
 {
    ...
 }
```

if the `-` is always present in the filenames you are interested in

or

```
 if (filename.StartsWith("abc-"))
 {
    ...
 }
```

if the filenames always start with `abc-` for the ones you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

you can do `if(filename.StartsWith ("abc-") )` or you can do `if (filename.Contains ( "-" ) )` or you can do `string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory, "abc-*.Zip");`

Answer (score 1):

```
// Consider using this overload:
// public static string[] GetFiles( string path, string searchPattern)

string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory, "abc*.zip");
```

Alternatively, you can use a regular expression as follows:

```
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
{
   if(Regex.Match (filename, @"abc.*?\.zip", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
   {
      // i want to do something
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\docs\folder\").ToList();
var g = from String s in files where s.StartsWith("abc") select s;
foreach(var z in g)
{
   //Do stuff in here as a replacement for your if
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression that matches your filenames, something along thees lines:

```
string sPattern = "abc-\d+\.zip";

string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory); 
foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
{
  // here i need to compare , i mean i want to get only these files which are having these type of  filenames `abc-19870908.Zip`
  if(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(filename , sPattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
  {

       // i want to do something
  }

}
```

The regular expression "abc-\d+.zip" means 
the string "abc-" followed by any number of digits, followed by a . followed by the string "zip" ([regular expression syntax](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet))